# match input elements with keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am not sure what's going on here..  I am trying to just match the val on  an input from a variable, and every time I try, I get an object, object.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GLnQx/1/

It's this piece of script that is screwing me up:

```
$("input.numberOfAccounts").keyup(function () {
$("input.pricingPerAccount").val($(newPricePerAccount));
});
```

newPricePerAccount will show me the correct number on alert, but when I try to put it in a val, it's no good.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't test with "alert". Use console.log. Also you should probably be using blur event instead of keyup.

Answer (score 1):

`$()` is the jQuery selector method.  `newPricePerAccount` is 5050, so it is trying to select a 5050 element (i.e. nothing), and it returns an object.  I think you just want

```
.val(newPricePerAccount)
```

Comment: This breaks the keyup function..  Why is the keyup function working originally and then when I try your code, it stops working?  Very strange.

Comment: You my have a typo, because it doesn't break for me: http://jsfiddle.net/GLnQx/3/

Comment: It does.  It does one keyup replace and then doesn't do anything on new values inputted.  Is the keyup function not set up properly??

Comment: It does something for me .. what exactly are you expecting?  How is it breaking?  I take breaking to mean it stops working entirely.

Comment: Ahh.  I mean when you change the input, the input under it should change from that giant if statement it goes through..  I updated the fiddle for the variable to be multiplied by something, and magically, it works: http://jsfiddle.net/GLnQx/5/ but doesn't give me the result I want.  I just want the variable and not it multiplied by something on a keyup.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$("input.pricingPerAccount").val(newPricePerAccount);
```

Comment: Keyup function breaks when I try this.

Comment: Don't test with "alert". Use console.log. Also you should probably be using blur event instead of keyup.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your jsFiddle, `newPricePerAccount` is a JS variable, correct? In that case, you don't need the `$()` selector on it.

`$` is only used to select DOM elements, not variables:

```
$('input.pricingPerAccount').val(newPricePerAccount);
```

Comment: Keyup function breaks when I try this.